# Reset skytex primer pocket

Tags: factory-reset

My son has a Skytex Primer Pocket, which he put a pattern unlock on. He has completely forgotten it. I've been trying to figure out what I might do. There is nothing of any importance on the device, I'm perfectly willing to do a factory reflash if possible, but I just can't figure out how to do anything. Anyone out there know what to do?

Comment: i believe if you enter the incorrect pattern a number of times, you will be allowed to log in with your google account.

Comment: That works for a standard device, but the Skytex doesn't have google services, and thus you can't use google to unlock it.

Answer (score 5):

I [found](http://www.slatedroid.com/topic/21719-all-about-skytex/page__view__findpost__p__251186) that you should be able to do a factory reset by holding the power and home when powering on. There you should have the option to do a factory reset.

Answer (score 2):

What I finally ended up doing was upgrading the firmware. I tried the home/power method, but it just wasn't working for me... Upgrading the firmware instructions are found on [their site](http://www.skytex.com/support/primer-pocket-drivers-firmwares). It wasn't too hard to do, except for the fact that they don't seem to have signed drivers, which forced me to use a non-64 bit system to do the upgrade.